# MySQL REGEXP: Find string exept between two characters

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to be able to select rows from a table where a given String appears in a TEXT column *unless* the only appearance of that string is in between two backticks.

For example, if I wanted all rows where the 'Message' column contained 'foo'...

'something **foo** something'

would be returned but

'something `something **foo** something ` something'

would not

This is what I have so far but I understand why this really doesn't work. I'm fairly new to REGEXP and can't think where to go with this next.

```
SELECT * FROM Posts 
WHERE Message REGEXP '[^`]*foo[^`]*';
```

Comment: Maybe ``WHERE Message LIKE '%foo%' AND WHERE Message NOT LIKE '%`%foo%`%'`` will do?

Comment: What if there are 3 bactics in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
WHERE Message LIKE '%foo%' AND WHERE Message NOT LIKE '%`%foo%`%'
```

That is, `LIKE '%foo%'` checks if a record contains `foo` and `NOT LIKE '%`%foo%`%'` makes sure that there is no `foo` inside backticks.

Comment: But if does the wrong thing for `a'b'c foo d'e'f`.  (I am using `'` for ease of formatting.)

Comment: @RickJames No, `foo` is in between apostrophes here.

Comment: Well, it is and it isn't.  If backtics are paired up, then it is not. Is:  `'c foo d'`  versus is not: `b` and `e` are inside; everything else is not.  Consider parens, instead:  `a(b)c foo d(e)f`.

Comment: @RickJames It looks as if you want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The Question is somewhat ambiguous.  What should happen for each of these:

```
a`b`c foo d`e`f  -- technically, "foo" is between a pair of backtics
a`b`c foo `end of string -- odd number of backtics
```

Assuming the backtics are "paired":

```
REGEXP "^([^`]*(`[^`]*`))*[^`]*foo"
```

Notes

```
[^`]*  -- many string without a backtic, even the empty string
(`[^`]*`)  -- match a string inside a pair of backtics
(...)* -- match any number of such, then
*[^`]*foo -- match "foo" not in paired backtics.
```

If the backtics are "paired", it might have been better to ask the question using parens or brackets or braces.